# $K[x]$ is not isomorphic with $K[[x]]$

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, vector-spaces, modules

> Let $K$ be a field. Prove that $K[x]$ is not isomorphic with $K[[x]]$ as $K$-vector spaces.

My solution: since $K $ is a field, $K[x]$ is pid then is noetherian ring. So every ideal of $K[x]$ is finite generated but $K[[x]]$ has an ideal such that it is not finite generated.

My questions are

1. Is my solution right??
2. Is there another way to prove this without using noetherian and finite generated of $K[x]$

Comment: What is $k$? Do you mean $K$ every place you use $k$?

Comment: What is the ideal of $K[[x]]$ that you think is not finitely generated?  The only ideals of $K[[x]]$ are of the form $(x^n)$.

Comment: @Thomas andrews. I corrected that

Comment: @erfan You are actually trying to prove they're not isomorphic as rings, which is not relevant as far as the structure of vector space is concerned. For instance, $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ are isomorphic as vector spaces, but not as rings. By the way, both $K[x]$ and $K[[x]]$ are noetherian domains, even PIDs, so your argument doesn't work. They are not isomorphic as rings for example because one is local and the other one isn't: $(x)$ and $(x+1)$ are distinct maximal ideals in $K[x]$, but $K[[x]]$ has only one maximal ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, by $K$-module, you are really talking about vector spaces, and they are isomorphic if and only if they each have a basis of the same cardinality.

The size of the basis for $K[x]$ is easily seen to be the cardinality of the natural numbers.

Can the basis of $K[[x]]$ be the cardinality of the natural numbers?

It's not clear why you are talking about ideals, since the properties of these sets as $K$-modules has nothing to do with the ring properties.

As commenter above notes, though, your ideal argument is also just wrong. The only ideals in $K[[x]]$ are of the form $x^nK[[x]]$, so the ring is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: I think $K[[x]]$ is not notherian

Comment: Your suggestion is  explore $K[x]$ as vector space on $K$??

Comment: If $K$ is a field, then a $K$-module is a vector space over $K$. So that is what the question asks.

Comment: Do you mean $K[[x]]$ is not Noetherian as a ring, or not Noetherian as a $K$-module (aka a vector space over $K$?)

Comment: How can compute size of cardinality of $K[[x]]$

Comment: As a  $K$-module

Comment: @erfan Neither $K[x]$ nor $K[[x]]$ is Noetherian as a $K$-module. They are  both Noetherian as rings.

Comment: Thank you very much @ thomas andrews